# Multi DataGridViews header alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have multi datagridViews in a form, when i scroll any one of these datagridViews, all datagridview will show the same firstdisplaycolumn, but when i scroll the hscroll bar to the end, i found if some datagridViews have vscroll bar some haven't, the dataGridView headr has a little miss alignment. How to make sure all header columns not any shift?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7EU70aNz_IaSlpDM0R3ZHY4QlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the link DOESN'T lead to any picture, What actually do you want to ask here?

Comment: Sorry, it my fault

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7EU70aNz_IaSlpDM0R3ZHY4QlU/edit?usp=sharing

this link is right

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the answer is as simple, but i feel you have to keep the column width fixed and same in each of the datagridview to show everything in the proper order when you check it in v-scroll bar.

Comment: if you are not using Tables in the gridview, prefer using tables for alignment